# AngularJS - Building a dynamic table based on a json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given a json like this:

```
{
   "name": "john"
   "colours": [{"id": 1, "name": "green"},{"id": 2, "name": "blue"}]
}
```

and two regular html inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="color" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

I need to build a table with all the possible variations, ex:

```
John green
John blue
```

That means that if a user continues adding values through the inputs new rows will appear building the new variations, for instance:

I also need to have available the id to handle it, and I need that when I add new values using the inputs for instance: "Peter" "Black", I need to autofill the id (colour id) dynamically like an auto increment in mysql, resulting in something like this:

```
{
  "colours": […...{"id": 3, "name": "black"}]
}
```

Is that possible? Which options do I have for doing that with angular? I'm still thinking in the jQuery way and I would like to do it in the angular way.

I took a look to hg-repeat, and used it, but I'm not figuring out how to deliver the expected result, the only thing that come to my mind was to use nested ng-repeats, but it didm´t work.

Thanks so much in advance,

Guillermo

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just want to share with what I used so far to save your time.

Here are examples of *hard-coded headers* and *dynamic headers* (in case if don't care about data structure). In both cases I wrote some simple directive: `customSort`

**customSort**

```
.directive("customSort", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,    
        scope: {
          order: '=',
          sort: '='
        },
        template : 
          ' <a ng-click="sort_by(order)" style="color: #555555;">'+
          '    <span ng-transclude></span>'+
          '    <i ng-class="selectedCls(order)"></i>'+
          '</a>',
        link: function(scope) {

        // change sorting order
        scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {       
            var sort = scope.sort;

            if (sort.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder){
                sort.reverse = !sort.reverse;
            }                    

            sort.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;        
        };


        scope.selectedCls = function(column) {
            if(column == scope.sort.sortingOrder){
                return ('icon-chevron-' + ((scope.sort.reverse) ? 'down' : 'up'));
            }
            else{            
                return'icon-sort' 
            } 
        };      
      }// end link
    }
    });
```

### [1st option with static headers]

I used single `ng-repeat`

This is a good example in <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/1758/)**</kbd>  (*Notice, there is no jQuery library!*)

[image]

```
           <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

### [2nd option with dynamic headers]

Demo 2: <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/2281/)**</kbd>

---

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th ng-repeat="header in table_headers"  
                     class="{{header.name}}" custom-sort order="header.name" sort="sort"
                    >{{ header.name }}

                        </th> 
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <div class="pagination pull-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                            </li>

                            <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length, currentPage, currentPage + gap) "
                                ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                            ng-click="setPage()">
                                <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                            </li>

                            <li ng-class="{disabled: (currentPage) == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tfoot>
            <pre>pagedItems.length: {{pagedItems.length|json}}</pre>
            <pre>currentPage: {{currentPage|json}}</pre>
            <pre>currentPage: {{sort|json}}</pre>
            <tbody>

                <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sort.sortingOrder:sort.reverse">
                     <td ng-repeat="val in item" ng-bind-html-unsafe="item[table_headers[$index].name]"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

---

*As a side note:*

The `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is deprecated, so I used it only for Demo (2nd example). You welcome to edit.

Comment: Could you provide a full live example on the 2nd with dynamic headers? :)

Comment: @devH Thanks for comment. I changed dramatically my answer with both working examples.

Comment: Same here, big thanks for that answer very informative

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of one with dynamic columns and rows with angularJS: http://plnkr.co/edit/0fsRUp?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

[TGrid](http://grid.tesseris.com/) is another option that people don't usually find in a google search. If the other grids you find don't suit your needs, you can give it a try, its free

Comment: Thanks! I´ve finally built something on my own. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [angular-table](http://github.com/samu/angular-table) directive.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in headers | filter:headerFilter | orderBy:headerOrder" width="{{header.width}}">{{header.label}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-class-odd="'trOdd'" ng-class-even="'trEven'" ng-dblclick="rowDoubleClicked(user)">
        <td ng-repeat="(key,val) in user | orderBy:userOrder(key)">{{val}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

refer this https://gist.github.com/ebellinger/4399082

Answer (score 0):

First off all I would like to thanks @MaximShoustin.

Thanks of you I have really nice table.

I provide some small modification in `$scope.range` and `$scope.setPage`.

In this way I have now possibility to go to the last page or come back to the first page.
Also when I'm going to next or prev page the navigation is changing when `$scope.gap` is crossing. And the current page is not always on first position. For me it's looking more nicer.

Here is the new fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLBRZ/3/