# generate dynamic template with directive parameters

Tags: angularjs

I create a directive to dynamically generate tables... the directive should contact the data service an then show some rows, the rows head is id, name, regions.

```
<planets data="{ view: 'planets', params: ['id','name','regions'] }"></planets>


test.directive('planets', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'data' : '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{data.params}}!</div>'
    }

});
```

i need a advice how to generate the

```
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>regions</th>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

dynamic? and how to pass the data out of the service to the

iam not shur to use template or link?

thanks!

**EDIT:**

```
test.controller('projects', function ($scope, DataService, $resource) {

    DataService.query(function(response) {
        $scope.projects = response;
    });

});

test.directive('planets', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            'data' : '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/table.html'
    };

});
```

Comment: Is `'data' : '='` working for you?

Comment: yes it is...my template show the params array!

Comment: People also had problem that you have, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json

Answer (score 1):

It depends how dynamic you need to be.  However, to generate your sample, you only need an `ng-repeat` inside the template:

```
template: '<table><tr><th ng-repeat="param in data.params">{{param}}</th></tr></table>'
```

Comment: How i get the scope.projects in my directive? Only with ng-controller? or is there another way? i updated first post!

Comment: just add another directive scope variable: `projects: "="` and set a projects attribute. same way as you are doing for data.