# Displaying dynamic JSON in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

From a web service I am getting a JSON string. It may vary based on the request. 2 JSON result are

**Result 1**

```
[
  {
    "Key": 1,
    "ID": 1,
    "applicationId": "1",
    "applicationName": "APP1"
  },
  {
    "Key": 2,
    "ID": 1,
    "applicationId": "2",
    "applicationName": "APP2"
  }
]
```

**Result 2**

```
[
  {
    "OrgKey": 1,
    "ID": 1,
    "OrgID": "1",
    "OrgName": "Org1"
  },
  {
    "OrgKey": 2,
    "ID": 4,
    "OrgID": "6",
    "OrgName": "Org2"
  }
]
```

How will I display this in a table?

In controller js file I use the `$http.get` method and in Success method I put

```
$scope.resultData = data;
```

But in HTML how I will display the dynamic contents?

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat = "result in resultData">
     <!-- Not the right way -->
     <!-- Here I want to put the headers like "Key,ID" ... -->
    </th>
   </tr> </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat = ""result in resultData">
   <td> {{result.Key }} </td>
   <!-- When the firlds vary, how to put? ->
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible? If so How? Thanks.

Comment: see this answer, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json/18357643#18357643

Comment: Based on http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http, be sure that you implement `$http.get` by right way (async call). Otherwise, HTML will show nothing.

Comment: But there the JSON format is same.

Comment: in my response I posted 2nd example with dynamic table

Answer (score 11, accepted):

first of all you should get first row to set your table's header like this

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in resultData[0]">
      {{header}}
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

after this for your `tbody` you should get your rows first then inside the row travel all cells,

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in resultData">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
      {{cell}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/rpXPUM57vf8yu8CvECEQ?p=preview)...

**UPDATE**

some users asked for if this can be handle without sorting headers and their values...

the answers is **yes** but before starting you should know why it is already sorted alphabetacally...

angular `ng-repeat` directive works differentlly with arrays and objects... If you use array you can make it sortable but this is not an option for objects here is a [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210) about it...

so right now best way is pushing object values into array before we use them in ng-repeat..

here is second [PlUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/p6E3IKf02LV2CP19MpzW?p=preview)

**NOTE : You will see I remove $$hashKey from array, because they are not a property of original element, angular add them into object automatically to watch changes**

Comment: hi. i just wanted to know if this can be done without the sorting of the rows! Right now the table headers are being sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build a dynamic table off of some other people's examples and documentation. http://jsfiddle.net/lastlink/v7pszemn/1/

```
<tr>
    <th class="{{header}}" ng-repeat="(header, value) in items[0]" ng-click="changeSorting(header)">
    {{header}}
  <i ng-class="selectedCls2(header)"></i>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="row in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sort.sortingOrder:sort.reverse">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
          {{cell}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

although the columns are out of order, on my .net project they are in order.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is not the best solution but it did work perfectly for me. in my 
current project im streaming data using webSocket and need to dynamically display it in ui as soon as i get data from server.

so the solution was quite simple and did what i wanted...

wrapping up function in a $timeout.

```js
vm.testErrors = [];

socket.onmessage(function(event) {    
  if (event.data !== 'connected') {
    $timeout(function() {
      addNewTestWithError(event.data);
    }, 0);
  } 
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.testErrors>
  <h3>{{item.fullTitle}}</h3>
  <h4>{{item.error}}</h4>
</div>
```

hope it helps