# AngularJS - Swipe effect with Pager

Tags: angularjs, pagination, swipe

I am using Pagination for my list of records. It is working correctly.

I need to implement Swipe effect so i used :-

```
<script src=".../angular-touch.min.js"></script>
```

The swipe effect do works, but records do not change. When i click Next nothing happens. I have noticed that i get `page` as `undefined` in `recentRecords(page)`

```
<pager total-items="recenttotalItems" page="currentPage" items-per-page="recentitemsperpage" max-size="maxsize" on-select-page="recentRecords(page)" ng-swipe-left="recentRecords(page)" ng-swipe-right="recentRecords(page)" class="pagination-sm"
                        previous-text="<<" next-text=">>"></pager>
```

How to pass current page number?

Comment: use currentPage instead of page and see what happens

Comment: Maybe this example might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json/18357643#18357643