# ng table with data from http request

Tags: angularjs

Does anyone have a decent example with ng-table loading data upon a success callback from http service?

```
this.getData = function(){      
        tmp = this; 
        tmp.loading = true; 

        $http.post('/fetch', 
            $.param({
                service_request: JSON.stringify(this.session)           
            }
            )).success(function(data) {             
                tmp.loading = false; 
                tmp.tableData = data;

        });
    };
```

I would like to build the table from the tableData variable.

Thanks

Comment: This post my help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json/18357643#18357643

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one way of doing it.

Create a service to get the table data (I just picked the code from your :

```
app.factory('getTableData', function($http) {
  return {
    getData: function(session){
              return $http.post('/fetch',
              {
                service_request: session
              }))
    }
  }
})
```

Then you inject the service in your controller:

```
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function(getTableData, $scope, $window) {

   $scope.loadTable = function(){
     getTableData.getData(JSON.stringify($window.session)) //not sure where you have the session variable stored.
     .sucess(function(data){
        $scope.tableData = data;
     })
     .error(function(){
       //do something
     })

   }
})
```

The HTML should be pretty straightforward:

```
<button ng-click="loadTable()">Load Table</button>

<table ng-table class="table">
<tr ng-repeat="row in tableData">
    <td data-title="'Property1'">{{row.Property1}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Property2'">{{row.Property2}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my problem is with the sorting (initial and ongoing), how do I do that?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation examples? http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1

Comment: Yes, I tried applying them to my app and it didnt work