# How to generate an HTML table from the following Hierachical Json?

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table, hierarchical-data

I have got JSON like this, You can find the complete JSON in the [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/tioP9wcBqzpsMU9jlnY8?p=preview)

```
"name": "TOTAL",
            "imageURL": "",
            "type": "Total",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "MOTOR CAR",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "MOTOR CAR",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Private",
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "Private",
                            "size": 9221
                        },
                        {
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "Hiring",
                            "name": "Hiring",
                            "size": 1058
                        },
                        {
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "Rent",
                            "name": "Rent",
                            "size": 114
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 10393
                },
                {
                    "name": "COMBINE HARVESTER",
                    "imageURL": "",
                    "type": "COMBINE HARVESTER",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "imageURL": "",
                            "type": "Agricultural Usage",
                            "name": "Agricultural Usage",
                            "size": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "size": 1
                }
      }
```

From the above I need to generate a table like as follows, how can I do that? Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
   <table>
        <tr ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr'>
            <td>
                {{key}} 
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in val'>  
                {{nestedVal}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: Your Plunkr points to something else. There is no json in that .

Comment: @brute_force Sorry, please check the updated one

Comment: Are you dealing with arrays or objects? your json structures are very different in the example above and in your plunker.

Comment: @o4ohel Yes, no its the same, i have posted only the first object here , that's why it looks different

Comment: hey checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json maybe this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected :

```
<tr ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr.children'>
            <td>
                {{key}} 
            </td>
            <td>
                {{val.name}} 
            </td>
           <td> 
             <div ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in val.children'>
               {{nestedVal.name}}
               </div>
            <td>
                {{val.size}} 
            </td>

        </tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/h4wxF7XS5Dk1kdQuyxLV?p=preview

Comment: Your ng-repeat  didnt' have any problems. Its just that you were traversing the json incorrectly. I will recommend using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to visualize your json.

Comment: although that does not render the expected output

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Vehicle Type</th>
        <th>Vehicle Usage</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="group in arr.children">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in group.children">
        <td>{{$parent.$index+1}}_{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{group.type}}</td>
        <td>{{item.type}}</td>
        <td>{{item.size}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```