# Angular2 table binding

Tags: data-binding, angular, 2-way-object-databinding, angular2-forms

So I am asking here about the concept of binding a table.
Usually it is pretty straight forward just use ngFor for all rows/columns.

However what I would like to do is that, for each cell it should be binded to an object of two attributes:

1. Cell Content
2. Header of the column, which is shared between all cells in that column.

In my table I should be able to add a row or a column as I want.
Which is simple, but all cells sharing column_header is the tricky part.

Now this table represent a form, so I can do processing after the user clicks submit and solve the issue.

I am just looking for other smarter ideas.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT| Clarification example**
Given the object from this post:
[AngularJS - Building a dynamic table based on a json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json)

Object

```
{
   "name": "john"
   "colours": [{"id": 1, "name": "green"},{"id": 2, "name": "blue"}]
}
```

I wanted to be something like that

```
{
       "name": "john",
       "colours": [
         {
           "id": 1, 
           "column":{
             "name": "green",
             "header":"H1"
            }
          },
         {
           "id": 2,
           "column":{
             "name": "blue",
             "header":"H1"
            }
          }
         ]
}
```

Where the header attribute is shared between both

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "sharing colum header"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I mean in each column object .. the column header name will be the same. Check in the example header attribute value is H1 for both objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways:

1. iterate your original objects and generate new objects based on your requirement and structure.
2. in `ngFor` you can use index, to get the index of the column, then you can use the index to get that column header. you can check the [api](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngFor)