# Multiple tables usig ng-repeat in AngularJS freezes browser for a while

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need multiple tables inside an accordion in angular js.
I am using the following code to do that.

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
   <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="look_up in lookup">
     <uib-accordion-heading>
     {{look_up.name}} - {{look_up.status}} <i ng-class="{'fa fa-spinner fa-spin':look_up.status=='Loading...','fa fa-check':look_up.status=='IN SYNC','fa fa-times':look_up.status=='NOT IN SYNC'}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
     </uib-accordion-heading>
    <label for="showOnlyFailed">Show only queries that failed?</label>
    <input id="showOnlyFailed" type="checkbox" ng-model="filter.valueField5"/>
    <table ng-table="table[$index]" class="table" show-filter="true">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'title1'" filter="{ valueField1: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField1'">
          {{user.valueField1}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title2'" filter="{ valueField2: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField2'">
          {{user.valueField2}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title3'" filter="{ valueField3: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField3'">
          {{user.valueField3}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title4'" filter="{ valueField4: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField4'">
          {{user.valueField4}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title5'" filter="{ valueField5: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField5'">
          {{user.valueField5}}
        </td>            
        <td title="'title6'" filter="{ valueField6: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField6'">
          {{user.valueField6}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title7'" filter="{ valueField7: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField7'">
          {{user.valueField7}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title8'" filter="{ valueField8: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField8'">
          {{user.valueField8}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title9'" filter="{ valueField9: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField9'">
          {{user.valueField9}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title10'" filter="{ valueField10: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField10'">
          {{user.valueField10}}
        </td>
        <td title="'title11'" filter="{ valueField11: 'text'}" sortable="'valueField11'">
          {{user.valueField11}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </uib-accordion-group>    
</uib-accordion>
```

The browser hangs for sometime before loading the tables.There are around 14 tables.How to optimize it .Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have performance issues is due to the implementation of `ng-repeat`.

`ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each item inside the array you are iterating through. Because Angular creates 2way binding between parent and child scopes, you  end up creating a lot of watches (which take most of the loading time).

If  you change "uib-accordion" to a custom accordion, you can lazy load each table :

```
<div ng-repeat="look_up in lookup">
    <div class="title" 
         ng-click="itemSelected = $index;">

         {{look_up.name}} - {{look_up.status}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="itemSelected == $index">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="">  ...  </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS : there are a lot of ways to deal with this issue. I choose the simplest to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.Will try to change it

Comment: Loading the data was not an issue for me.Creating multiple ng-tables inside accordion makes the browser hang.Is there any way to create the tables dynamically only after the accordion is opened?

Comment: @Chandrasekar  [Dynamic tables Directives](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18357643/452708)

Comment: @Chandrasekar that's what I did with my ng-if in fact, and what I meant by "lazy load" tables, sorry I was not clear explaining it.