# How to display json data in two columns with table in each column using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data in my json it will be dynamic and I want to display the data in a table with two columns and each column contains a table.

```
This is my json: var data = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c":3, "d": "4", "e": "5"}
```

My html code.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>a</td>
              <td>1</td>
           </tr>
        </table>   
     </td>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>b</td>
              <td>2</td>
           </tr>
        </table>   
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>c</td>
              <td>3</td>
           </tr>
        </table>   
     </td>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>d</td>
              <td>4</td>
           </tr>
        </table>   
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>5</td>
           </tr>
        </table>   
     </td>         
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to this dynamically in angularjs using ng-repeat. How do I do this?
I want it to display like this.

```
a  1   b 2
c  3   d 4
e  5
```

I tried but could not split into two columns. Here is my code.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat=" (key, value) in data track by index">
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>{{key}}</th>
                <td>{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any tries? please post your code

Comment: Take a look on my answer related to create dynamic table based on JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json/18357643#18357643

Comment: @MaximShoustin Your answer does not solve my problem. I just want to split json into two columns.

Comment: because objects doesn't hold to any specific key/value ordering you might want to first turn that object into an array of key/value pair or something similar and sort them, I would also use 2 ngRepeats...

Comment: @svarog 17 Hi, turning object into an array of key/value pair would help but can you please elaborate on using 2 ngRepeats. How would you use it? Thanks!