# how to fix a header for a dyanamic table getting data from database

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to set a fixed position for header of the table where this table data is coming from database where different queries has different tables? The header in each of the queries are different. As of now i have sent only code for the table and it used in bottom slide of the page.

```css
#datatable {
  width: 100 % ;
  text - align: center;
  border: 1 px solid #000;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;  
  -ms-user-select: none;     
  user-select: none;
  font-size:small;
}

#datatable thead {
  background: aquamarine;
}

#datatable thead tr {
  border - bottom: 1 px solid# aaa;
}

#datatable tbody, tr {
  border - bottom: 1 px solid# aaa;
}

#datatable th, td {
  border - right: 1 px solid# aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="queryTableId" style="float: left; height: 170px; width: 75%; overflow: scroll;">

    <table id="datatable" st-table="displayCollection" st-safe-src="dataList[0].data.rows" class="table table-striped" ng-hide="queryTableHidden">
        <thead>
            <tr style="height:30px;">
                <th ng-repeat="column in dataList[0].data.cols" st-sort="{{column}}">{{column | uppercase}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in displayCollection" ng-click="selectedFeature(row,$index)" id="row-{{$index}}" style="height: 20px;">
                <td ng-repeat="item in row">{{ item }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357370/angularjs-building-a-dynamic-table-based-on-a-json/18357643#18357643

Comment: i am recieving dyanamic data but i want to fix the dyanamic header fixed

Comment: i cant get what do you mean by dynamic header fixed.can you make it more clear?

Comment: according to query, i get tables from database. each table is having a different headings in head division, i got the solution for this but i cannot able to fix the header while scrolling the rows(approx 800).